# Need Appium code to relanch app in between test case

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium-android, application-restart, close-application

I am new to automation(looking for help), 
My scenario is - I need to restart the app and have to check the last data inserted should be auto saved

driver.closeApp is not working ( i already tried)
And I don't want to use this code in app launch method, I want to make an another method for that

Comment: In your Desired Capabilities "noReset" : "false" then do driver.quit() & launch the app using driver.launch()

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use following method to put you application in background, it will relaunch the application after 10 sec automatically, after relaunch app will make server calls :

```
 driver.runAppInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

2. Reset the currently running app for this session and wait until it is installed again.

   `driver.resetApp();`
3. Terminate the app and activate again , pass Package name for Android

   `driver.terminateApp('com.apple.Preferences');
     driver.activateApp('com.apple.Preferences');`